# Is it possible to perform Semantic Textual Similarity without using NLTK and Genism?

Tags: python, semantic-similarity

College restricted us to make projects in object oriented programming languages but without using any other libraries except standard ones. We can not use APIs also

Comment: you must provide more details as to what is requested and what you can use in order to recieve an answer

Comment: one can always implement some (simplified versions of) ML algorithms from scratch